# How can I remove nested lists encompassing all of my elements within a list?

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm reading in a .csv file into a list and the output list contains nested lists for each string element.I need to my list to contain only string elements. Am I using the csv module incorrectly?

```
import csv
import os

with open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Tracking_Info/kw_tracking_numbers.csv"), 'r') as tracking:
    reader = csv.reader(tracking)
    TrackList = list(reader)
    print(TrackList)
```

Expected output: `['PL431243161', 'PL431245166', 'PL423032770']`

Actual output: `[['PL431243161'], ['PL431245166'], ['PL423032770']]`

Comment: Post the content of the CSV file

Comment: it looks like you just have a new-line delimited file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe we can modify the code in this way:

```
import csv
import os

with open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Tracking_Info/kw_tracking_numbers.csv"), 'r') as tracking:
    TrackList = [i[0] for i in csv.reader(tracking)]

    print(TrackList)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a .CSV file using `csv.reader`, each item returned from iterating the reader is a sequence of the delimited values in the item.  If you have one column, you get a list with one thing for each line.

Your file isn't really .CSV if it has no delimiters.  Each line is a single string, so just read in the lines:

```
import os

with open(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/Tracking_Info/kw_tracking_numbers.csv"), 'r') as tracking:
    TrackList = tracking.read().splitlines()
    print(TrackList)
```